# Install driver during project installation

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, driver

I am trying to install a drive programatically during my program's installation. I have tried several things and none of them appear to be installing my driver.

Things I have tried based on Google/Stack searching:

**Method 1:**

set attribute: `[DllImport("DIFxAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]`

```
result = DriverPackagePreinstall(tempPath + "umpusbXP.inf", Flags);

if (result != 0)
MessageBox.Show("Driver 'umpusbXP.inf' installation failed.");
```

where `Flags` have been set to various combinations of

```
//0x00000010 
Int32 DRIVER_PACKAGE_LEGACY_MODE = 16;
//0x00000004
Int32 DRIVER_PACKAGE_FORCE = 4;
//0x00000008
Int32 DRIVER_PACKAGE_ONLY_IF_DEVICE_PRESENT = 8;
```

Doesn't seem to work. It will return various errors, some of which I'm able to find the meaning of on the internet, other not. the most common one is `0xE0000304 ERROR_INVALID_CATALOG_DATA => no cat` (which I found [at](http://git.libssh2.org/?p=libusb-pbatard.git;a=patch;h=refs/tags/a156)) The other errors had numbers which were not in that file or anywhere else I could find.

**Method 2:**

set attribute:

```
[DllImport("Setupapi.dll", EntryPoint = "InstallHinfSection", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern void InstallHinfSection(
                [In] IntPtr hwnd,
                [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle,
                [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer,
                int nCmdShow);
```

then used the method

```
InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, tempPath + "umpusbXP.inf", 0);
```

This method returns void so it is difficult to get any information from that. Needless to say it doesn't install the driver.

**Method 3:**

set attribute:

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
public static extern bool SetupCopyOEMInf(

    string SourceInfFileName,
    string OEMSourceMediaLocation,
    OemSourceMediaType OEMSourceMediaType,
    OemCopyStyle CopyStyle,
    string DestinationInfFileName,
    int DestinationInfFileNameSize,
    ref int RequiredSize,
    string DestinationInfFileNameComponent

    );
```

then used this method

```
string output ="";
int size = 0;
SetupCopyOEMInf(tempPath + "umpusbXP.inf", null, OemSourceMediaType.SPOST_PATH, OemCopyStyle.SP_COPY_OEMINF_CATALOG_ONLY, null, 0, ref size, output);
```

I'm using these methods to the best of my understanding but the documentation has been tricky to read. I keep checking my `setupapi.log` file for errors but none show up. How is one supposed to install drivers?